# Is it possible to map `alt+s` to escape in VSCode Vim?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using `alt+s` to escape in vim for a while. I'm now considering to try VSCode with its vim plugin. Is it possible to map `alt+s` to `extension.vim_escape`? Currently, `alt+s` opens "Selection" from the top menu bar.

I have tried adding the following to `keybindings.json`

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",
  "command": "extension.vim_escape"
}
```

as well as the following to `settings.json`

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": ["alt+s"],
            "after": ["<Esc>"]
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a custom keybinding in your `keybindings.json` file?  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Comment: @awh112 yes, but it doesnt override the default behavior.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was putting this binding into `keybindings.json` and reloading the editor.

```
[
    {
        "key": "alt+s",
        "command": "extension.vim_escape",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode == 'Insert'"
    }
]
```